# Trouble with geom_segment in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried plotting a path realisation of a compound Poisson process, but for some reason I keep getting one unecessary dshed line at x=0 with the geom_segment component. I don't know what's wrong. Don't mind the names, they're in Slovenian.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(42)
# Parameters
nSteps = 150
lambda = 0.1  # Intensity

# Generate sample path of HPP and CPP
jumpsHpp = rpois(nSteps, lambda)
samplePath = data.frame(time = 1:nSteps,
                    jumpTimes = jumpsHpp, 
                    gamma = rgamma(nSteps, shape = 20, rate = 1))

samplePath$value = cumsum(samplePath$gamma*samplePath$jumpTimes)

# Create an origin
new = data.frame(
  time = c(0, 1),
  jumpTimes = c(0, 0),
  gamma = c(0, 0),
  value = c(0, 0))

samplePath = rbind(new, samplePath[-1, , drop = FALSE])

# Create ggplot
g1 = ggplot() +
  geom_step(data = samplePath,
        aes(x = time, y = value),
        size = 1,
        color = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = samplePath$jumpTimes * 0:nSteps, y = -0.8),
         shape = "x",
         size = 3,
         color = "black") +
  geom_segment(data = data.frame(x = samplePath$jumpTimes * 0:nSteps,
                             yend = samplePath$value), 
           aes(x = x, xend = x, y = 0, yend = yend), 
           linetype = "dashed",
           color = "black") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  labs(title = lambda == 0.1~""~alpha == 20~" število korakov: 150",
       x = "Čas",
       y = "Vrednost")
```

Here's a photo of the graph that is generated. The inital black dashed line is the one that I can't get rid of.

[image]

Thank you in advance to whoever that helps!

Answer (score 2):

**Update: After clarification:**
To remove the very first x we have to exclude it from our data:

```
g1 = ggplot() +
  geom_step(data = samplePath,
            aes(x = time, y = value),
            size = 1,
            color = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = samplePath$jumpTimes * 0:nSteps, y = -0.8,
                 size = ifelse(samplePath$jumpTimes * 0:nSteps == 0 & -0.8 == -0.8, 0, 3)),
             shape = "x",
             color = "black") +
  geom_segment(data = data.frame(x = samplePath$jumpTimes * 0:nSteps,
                                 yend = samplePath$value) %>% 
                 dplyr::filter(x != 0),
               aes(x = x, xend = x, y = 0, yend = yend), 
               linetype = "dashed",
               color = "black") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  labs(title = paste("lambda =", lambda, "alpha =", 20, "število korakov:", nSteps),
       x = "Čas",
       y = "Vrednost") +
  scale_size_identity()  

g1
```

[image]
**First answer:**
Filter values where x is not 0 in your data frame:

added:

```
....%>% 
filter(x != 0),...
```

```
g1 = ggplot() +
  geom_step(data = samplePath,
            aes(x = time, y = value),
            size = 1,
            color = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = samplePath$jumpTimes * 0:nSteps, y = -0.8),
             shape = "x",
             size = 3,
             color = "black") +
  geom_segment(data = data.frame(x = samplePath$jumpTimes * 0:nSteps,
                                 yend = samplePath$value) %>% 
                 filter(x != 0),
               aes(x = x, xend = x, y = 0, yend = yend), 
               linetype = "dashed",
               color = "black") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  labs(title = lambda == 0.1~""~alpha == 20~" število korakov: 150",
       x = "Čas",
       y = "Vrednost")

g1
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this fix, although the x marking at the origin still remains. Is there a way to get rid of that too?